# Why does the WebBrowser control not display HTML correctly after it has been saved?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I've read a lot of related answers but I still don't see the problem. I think **MY** problem is that I don't have a good grasp of the basics of HTML and potentially javascript. I'm talking about how they are stuck together and operate, not the particular language syntax. Perhaps somebody could give me the big picture explanation of what is going wrong here.

I'm using a simple WebBrowser control to navigate to a web page. This results in everything displaying correctly. Now, I'd like to save that HTML content locally on the machine and open it again later, then render it in another WebBrowser control. This has not worked so far. The page renders briefly but without images and effects, then I get an exception regarding scripts. So I decided to do a very simple test. I would get the HTML from the browser, then immediately read that text back into the browser.

After navigating to the page successfully, I get the HTML text as follows:

```
string html = myWebBrowser.DocumentText;
```

I then immediately set the DocumentText property to its original value.

```
myWebBrowser.DocumentText = html;
```

This gives me the same error and effect as if my other application was reading the saved HTML. So what is going on here? The browser initially shows all content successfully but then extracting and reloading the HTML text breaks it all. I must be missing a very obvious and basic concept here. Is it that the WebBrowser control's DocumentText property does not actually return the original HTML code, but rather a modified version? Or is it that setting that property modifies something? Is it neither? Thanks to anyone who can sort out my understanding of how all this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. HTML is not a fully inclusive file. The browser will parse the html and pull resources from other urls including scripts, images, styles, etc. If you save only the html and then open that file in a browser, many of the resources will not be found since they rely on the html loading them from their location relative to the html file. Once the file is on your computer, any relative link to a resource will be invalid resulting in the browser only showing the basic html and any resources that have been referenced by absolute paths and not relative paths.

Comment: Ah, so it's a relative/absolute path problem. That makes more sense. I understood that the HTML document was like a list of instructions and locations for media files, but I thought that saving the file would mean I could open it later and follow those same instructions and paths to recreate the document again. So is there a painless way to save an offline version of the page with the WebBrowser control which has all the needed data packaged together? And thanks for your answer, too!

Comment: There is no easy way since html can be infinitely referenced. I.e. You download a very simple html file that references one script file. That script file can reference another script and more images. That script can then reference another script and even reference the first script so you can branch forever and run into circular references. This is why a browser is extremely difficult to build and there are only a handful of browsers that do this well. Your best bet would be to print the page or screen capture it. Modern web pages can't be saved for offline viewing.

Comment: Thank you. You've been extremely helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as the accepted answer if it answered your question. Thanks!